# Python Panel Data

Tags: python, panel

I am usually using Stata but now want to use Python and desperately trying to create a pandel data set. I tried pandas.panel but do not get it to work. 
I have the following dataset:

```
  date  id1   id2
  2000  100   50
  2001  101   48
```

Now I want to make it look like this:

```
    date  id   variable
    2000   1    100
    2000   2    101
    2001   1    50
    2001   2    48
```

Next, I want to identify a time and id variable to run some panel function. I also tried dataframe.stack(), but this doesn't sort according to the id. How do I do this or am I missing some nice time-series function in pandas here?

Sorry for the question. I am sure this has been answered somewhere, but I tried several hours now and cannot figure it out.

Comment: I have figured out that the problem is that I don't have an ID for the column as id1 and i2 columns are named with different strings.
But how do I assign an id to each column without distorting the dataset?

Comment: I believe some values in your variable column are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given input data:

```
data = [
    {"date": 2000, "id1": 100, "id2": 50},
    {"date": 2001, "id1": 101, "id2": 48}
]
```

or

```
data = {
    "date": [2000, 2001],
    "id1": [100, 101],
    "id2": [50, 48],
}
```

such that

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

"[melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html)" the pandas DataFrame:

```
melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars="date", var_name="id", value_name="variable")

# Optional amendments
melted["id"] = melted["id"].str.replace("id", "")
melted.sort_values(by="date", inplace=True)
melted.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

melted
```

`melted` Output

[image]

Additional Reference: Wickham, H. [*Tidy Data*](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html), The Journal of Statistical Software, 10, 59, 2014.

Comment: `melt` has a `var_name` and `value_name` parameter to do the rename in one step.

Comment: @DSM.  Thanks.  Fixed.