# Custom equations with bygroup and apply in pandas - MemoryError

Tags: pandas, memory, lambda, group-by, apply

All,

I am running code to calcluate a new variable (`newvar`) for each constituent (group) in a panel using the apply function:

```
df['newvar'] = df.groupby('group')['var1'].apply(lambda x : x - x.shift() + df['var2'] - df['var3'])
```

The code returns a memory error (**MemoryError**). I think what's happening is that the code generates a large number of separate dataframes which then causes the system to run out of memory because df itself is quite a large file. I can probalby do this with a for-loop, but is there a more verbose/computationally efficient way of doing this?

Many thanks,
Andres

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please provide a sample of your data. see the help centre article[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and more

Comment: I think this is pretty clear: group is a variable by which I group a panel dataset. Var1 is a varaible (column) to which I apply the lambda function. var2 and var3 are other variables (columns). The solution I found is this:

Comment: df2=pd.DataFrame()

for k,v in df.groupby('group'):
    v['newvar'] = (v['var1']-v['var1'].shift()+v['var2']-v['var3'])\
    df2 = df2.append(v)

Comment: The dataframe is the same as the second from the top as in this example, however, I have two more columns which are variables (var2 and var3). So id=group and variable=var1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848730/python-panel-data

Comment: I think I can answer this question now thanks to:

https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6